# Python- my variable doesn't give me a random number to output in a function (Module = Random)

Tags: python, random

The output is nothing when i enter all 5 numbers into each input, why is that?I tried all the different ways but i couldn't do it.

Here is my code--

```
    import random
r1 = random.randint(1, 5)
r2 = random.randint(1, 5)

print(r1, r2)

p1 = [int(input('1 - Enter a number from 1 to 5: ')), 'First Person']
p2 = [int(input('2 - Enter a number from 1 to 5: ')), 'Second Person']
p3 = [int(input('3 - Enter a number from 1 to 5: ')), 'Third Person']
p4 = [int(input('4 - Enter a number from 1 to 5: ')), 'Fourth Person']
p5 = [int(input('5 - Enter a number from 1 to 5: ')), 'Fifth Person']

if p1 == r1 or p1 == r2:
    print('ok')

if p2 == r1 or p2 == r2:
    print('ok')

if p3 == r1 or p3 == r2:
    print('ok')

if p4 == r1 or p4 == r2:
    print('ok')

if p5 == r1 or p5 == r2:
    print('ok')
```

Comment: Why do you have the `[]` around the assignments for `p1`, etc.  `p1`, etc are now lists of a single integer, not an integer.  They will never equal `r1` or `r2`.  Remove the `[]`.

Comment: All your `p<n>` variables are lists but you're comparing them to ints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import random

r1 = random.randint(1, 5)
r2 = random.randint(1, 5)

print(r1, r2)

numbers = [int(i) for i in input('Enter 5 numbers from 1 to 5: ').split()]

for i in numbers:
    if i == r1 or i == r2:
        print('ok')
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add the indice, such as:

```
if p1[0] == r1 or p1[0] == r2:
    print('ok')
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I think there is an indentation problem at the beginning of your code.
To answer your question, the problem is that p1, p2,... are not ints, but a list such as `[int, str]`.
So, your tests your should look like:

```
if p1[0] == r1 or p1[0] == r2:
    ...
```

Also, I advise you to make your code easier to read by doing something like that:

```
for p in [p1, p2, p3, p4, p5]:
    if p[0] in [r1, r2]:
         print('ok')
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the need for a list but in order to acheive what you're trying you will have to check the values against the element of the list by indexing and not the list itself.

It'd look something like this:

```
import random
r1 = random.randint(1, 5)
r2 = random.randint(1, 5)

print(r1, r2)

p1 = [int(input('1 - Enter a number from 1 to 5: ')), 'First Person']
p2 = [int(input('2 - Enter a number from 1 to 5: ')), 'Second Person']
p3 = [int(input('3 - Enter a number from 1 to 5: ')), 'Third Person']
p4 = [int(input('4 - Enter a number from 1 to 5: ')), 'Fourth Person']
p5 = [int(input('5 - Enter a number from 1 to 5: ')), 'Fifth Person']

if p1[0] == r1 or p1[0] == r2:
    print('ok')

if p2[0] == r1 or p2[0] == r2:
    print('ok')

if p3[0] == r1 or p3[0] == r2:
    print('ok')

if p4[0] == r1 or p4[0] == r2:
    print('ok')

if p5[0] == r1 or p5[0] == r2:
    print('ok')
```